# template_bundle_id for Fcebook JS

Tags: javascript, facebook

Can anyone please explain to me what is template_bundle_id for in Facebook JS.. Example below template_bundle_id is hardcoded:

```js
FB.Connect.showFeedDialog(
    53126803199, null, target, 
    null, null, FB.RequireConnect.promptConnect
);
```

1. What is the use of `template_bundle_id` if I can hardcode the  template_bundle_id?
2. Is unique `template_bundle_id` need to assign to each facebook js method that I call subsequently or I can use the same `template_bundle_id` number?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you cannot publish a feed story without having a template for it. The template defines the general content of the feed, and provides placeholders for variables.

Each template is uniquely identified with a template_bundle_id. It is called a *bundle* id because you define a template for short stories, full stories, etc.

Whenever you want to publish a feed story, you provide facebook with the `template_bundle_id` and the contents of the variables that are to be filled.

You can register template bundles either by code (if you have dynamic requirements for the templates, using `Feed.registerTemplateBundle`), or using the console [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools.php?feed).

You could just use one template, but all your feed stories would *look the same*.